# way to generate a specified number dataframe of new csv file from existing csv file in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have large data-frame in a Csv file sample1 from that i have to generate a new Csv file contain only 100 data-frame.i have generate code for it.but i am getting key Error the label[100] is not in the index?
I have just tried as below,Any help would be appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv("C:/users/raju/sample1.csv")
data_frame1 = data_frame[:100]
data_frame.to_csv("C:/users/raju/sample.csv")`
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
data_frame.iloc[:100]
```

A more efficient way to do it is to use `nrows` argument who purpose is exactly to extract portions of files. This way you avoid wasting resources and time parsing useless rows:

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv("C:/users/raju/sample1.csv", nrows=101)  # 100+1 for header
data_frame.to_csv("C:/users/raju/sample.csv")
```

Comment: i used this method but i am again getting the keyerror label [100] is not in the [index]'

Comment: I tried that also file generating but it is showing cprased errors